# how to fix npm error in Mac in visual studio code

Tags: node.js, macos, visual-studio-code, npm

How do I fix this error?

```
USER@Bahus-MacBook-Air metaplex-master % npm --version
8\.5.2
USER@Bahus-MacBook-Air metaplex-master % npm install
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /Users/USER/Desktop/solana devnet/metaplex-master/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/USER/Desktop/solana devnet/metaplex-master/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/USER/.npm/\_logs/2022-03-24T13_07_17_630Z-debug-0.log
```

How do I fix this npm installation error in visual studio code in Mac?

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that the path where you are executing `npm i` command doesn't have package.json file.
Make sure to change the path to the place where the package.json file is located.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are trying this project https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex

And you are probably running `npm install` in the main directory. But if you read the instalation [documentation](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex#installing) which you definitely should, then you would see `cd metaplex/js` which means you need to run `npm install` within the `./js` folder since that's where the `package.json` is, which is required by `npm install` command.